# Where do I place Googleservices.json in Flutter app in order to solve 'google-services.json is missing'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I get this error when i try building the default flutter app after integrating it with Firebase

I have placed the googleservices.json in the right place. Now it says it is searching for it in locations that are not there. like

```
src\debug\nullnull\google- services.json
```

this folder does not even exist, i have looked and it is not present.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Phone in debug mode...
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 
'implementation' instead.
 registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
 registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
 registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
 registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
 registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot 
function without it. 
Searched Location: 
C:\Users\rober\Documents\VS\APPNAME\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google- 
services.json
C:\Users\rober\Documents\VS\APPNAME\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google- 
services.json
C:\Users\rober\Documents\VS\APPNAME\android\app\src\nullnull\google- 
services.json
C:\Users\rober\Documents\VS\APPNAME\android\app\src\debug\google- 
services.json
C:\Users\rober\Documents\VS\APPNAME\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google- 
services.json
C:\Users\rober\Documents\VS\APPNAME\android\app\google-services.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Gradle build failed: 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to place it under `android/app`:

[image: location of google-service.json]

Also it should be named `google-services.json` without the space after the dash. To rename it right click on it then click Refactor>Rename.

Comment: hah I feel so stupid. I was placing it at the wrong directory. Thank you for the illustration and answer

Comment: @PeterHaddad one can also put them into `src/main` & `src/debug` source-sets.

Comment: The image shows it in the `android/app/src` directory.
However it is indeed supposed to be in the `android/app` directory!

Comment: @guivho actually not. If you look carefully, you will notice `src` directory is not expanded on the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `google-services.json` into `App_Resources/src` directory.