# Couldn't sync after adding depenency to gradle in VScode

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I tried to configure my flutter project in order to use firebase. I added all the dependency and couldn't sync after adding the lines mentioned in the firebase to Gradle build. 
How do I sync in **vscode**.

***added depenency for firebase:***

**In project -> android -> app -> build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**In project -> gradle -> build.gradle:**

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'**
    }
```

**IN project -> pubspec.yaml**

```
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
```

Also ran `flutter pub get`

***Error log:***

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\flutter_apps\time_tracker_flutter_course\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\flutter_apps\time_tracker_flutter_course\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 23s
  Command: C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\flutter_apps\time_tracker_flutter_course\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: add ur build.gradle and the pubspec.yaml

Comment: I have already added them as said in firebase docs. How do I sync them ?

Comment: i mean add them to the question to see what the issue is

Comment: Done added them...!!!!In the android studio, there will pop up at the right top corner to open the android module in android studio and that syncs the files. But how do I do that in VScode.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Firebase, you need to download the `google-services.json` file and add it to your project:

[Where do I place Googleservices.json in Flutter app in order to solve 'google-services.json is missing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783588/where-do-i-place-googleservices-json-in-flutter-app-in-order-to-solve-google-se/51783938#51783938)

Then in the `android/build.gradle`, you need to add the google() maven repository:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    ...
  }
}
```

and inside `android\app\build.gradle`, you need to add the `google-service` plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Check this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

Comment: Yes, since u are using flutter then the pubspec.yaml is equivalent to the build.gradle in native android development, when you add a dependency in pubspec.yaml and save it will automatically get that dependency, but again follow the steps to add firebase to make sure everything is correct and also don't forget to use minSdkVersion 21 instead of minSdkVersion 16

Comment: The error log is the full error i get and its mentioned in the question

Comment: Works now :) I messed up with firebase and google service versions.