# How to link firebase project with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I recently created a todo app in flutter so I want to read and write from a firebase project??
I have tried researching how to do that but I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a project in the firebase console, download the `google-services.json` and add it under android/app/ directory and then you can add the firebase plugins to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-realtime-database-with-flutter-ebd98aba2c91

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51783938/7015400